# Predicting with GAM and categorical predictors in R

Tags: r, predict, gam, mgcv, marginal-effects

I have some data for multiple users and I want to generate some marginal effects for each user using GAM modelling. **If I do this exercise for just a single user (John)** as:

`model_1 = mgcv::gam(y ~ s(speed) + s(length) + s(price), data1)` with `data1` having data only for John, then I can get the *speed-effect* with `prediction_1 = mgcv::predict.gam(model_1, test_set, type="response")` where `test_set` is a table with `speed` as sequence `seq(0,100,by=5)` , while both `length` and `price` are fixed at John's mean values. It is the same as running `plot(ggeffects::ggpredict(model_1), facets = TRUE)` .

Now, I want to repeat this exercise for John but with a model that includes **all my users**. Hence, I am having a categorical/factor variable `user_id` and run the following model:

`model_2 = mgcv::gam(y ~ user_id + s(speed) + s(length) + s(price), data2)` with `data2` having all users' data. Now, If I want to obtain again only John's *speed-effect* but with `model_2` , I am trying `predictions_2 = mgcv::predict.gam(model_2, test_set2, type="response")` where `test_set2` only having `test_set2$user_id="John"` , again `speed` as a (0-100) sequence and both `length` and `price` fixed at John's mean values.

The results from these two exercises, although I was expecting to be the same, are different. I have also tried `test_set2` with `length` and `price` fixed at all users' mean values but again I can not get identical results for John as with `prediction_1`.

Could you please help me understand what I am doing wrong or missing here? How can I obtain `prediction_1` results using the model with the categorical? Much appreciated.

Comment: In the first model, only John's values are used to generate the coefficients for speed, length and price.  In the second model, all users' values are being used to estimate the effects of speed, length and price, but with a an intercept for individuals, so John would have a different intercept, but the same effects as everyone else in model 2.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on [stats.se] but the OP has already posted the question there: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/608112/1390